# Google Sheet cell value original input 2-1-0 shows as 2-1-2000

Tags: google-sheets, cell

I am scraping the information from another website to Google Spreadsheets using js formula and getting back mismatching value data (2-1-0 shows as 2-1-2000)
Please could someone explain me in details how it works and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets spreadsheet engine interpret `2-1-0` as a date and display it accordingly to the default format settings for dates considering the spreadsheet language and regional settings.

If the original value it's not a date, you could make that a Google Apps Script function using UrlFetchApp add an apostrophe (`'`) as a prefix for those values: `'2-1-0`.

Comment: Thanks for your response and interest. Google Sheets does not require any coding  automatically scrape the data, but wouldn't let you regularly update constantly changing information therefore I am using simple js code to accomplish it.:function getData() { 
  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
  var queryString = Math.random(); 
  var cellFunction = '=IMPORTHTML("http://www.foxsports.com/nhl/standings","table",1)';

  sheetName.getRange('A1').setValue(cellFunction); 
  
}

Comment: @Vladislavs IMPORTHTML has ‘t a way to prevent the issue. You should use another way to import the dat like the use of urlfetchapp

Comment: Thanks a lot so I'll just go ahead and study " Apps Script UrlFetchApp API" just to get it done, but I still would like to understand how does cells in Google Sheets get so different values  and why.So what can I do for you to make your day happier?Maybe some likes and following..uh I don't know all I know everybody's time has to be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @Vladislavs : Basically, Google Sheets as well as other spreadsheets apps automatically try to figure out the data type for values, that is the way that they work.

Comment: and I am guessing under that meaning automatically must lay tons of code

Comment: @Vladislavs: Maybe you will find interesting https://ethercalc.net/ and https://www.openoffice.org/product/calc.html